# How to calculate percentage of "equal or better" in mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql

Figuring out a title for this question was hard, but the following is harder for me. I hope anyone can help.

I have a simple MySQL database table. This table is filled with records containing an ID and the number of week-visitors. It has records of 2 year of about 200+ websites.

To summarize, I want to be able to know two things:

1.) - "In week 54 of 2009 the website somethingonline.com had 300 visitors" (Easy of course. I can do this)

2.) - "The webiste sometingonline.com was among the 8% best scoring websites in that week."

Now, how can I get number 2.??? Of course, I want to know that percentage of all websites in every week so I get a list like:

1. sometingonline1.com - 300 visitors - 8% of the website score like this or better
2. sometingonline2.com - 400 visitors - 4% of the website score like this or better
3. sometingonline3.com - 500 visitors - 2% of the website score like this or better
4. sometingonline4.com - 600 visitors - 1% of the website score like this or better

How can I get these results? Is this possible in one query?

I use MySQL and PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to involve two different "copies" of your `visits` table. In this query `v1` represents the website you're actually looking at. For each of those `v1` websites, we'll join to a copy of the `visits` table, matching any row that covers a site with more visits in the same week.

```
SELECT v1.website_name, v1.visits, COUNT(v2.id)
FROM visits AS v1
INNER JOIN visits AS v2 ON (v1.week_number = v2.week_number AND v2.visits > v1.visits AND v2.id != v1.id)
WHERE week_number = 54
```

This will tell you the ***number*** of sites that had more visitors. To get that as a percentage, run a separate query to simply count the total number of sites that had *any* visits in that week. In your PHP script you can then do the simple division to get the percentage you want.

Comment: Thanks VoteyDisciple, I'm working this out right now and will come back on it. At WHERE week_number = 54 I now edited it to WHERE v1.week_number = 54. I think that is right, isn't it?

Comment: VoteyDisciple, it works! Thanks! One tiny little question though. If COUNT(v2.id) returns 0, all the other values are empty as well. How can I prevent this (so if a certain website has the highest visitors, it only returns empty values but also in that case I would like to get visitor numbers and website_name).